# Twitter privacy settings?

Tags: twitter, privacy

I tried to register a new Twitter account. The registration form said, that my full name will appear on my public profile. Is there a privacy setting for at least limit the people available to see my full name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the account name is always visible.  Of course, nothing is forcing you to actually set it to anything real :)

Comment: Actually they are forcing me to provide my full name. The form verification says "can't be blank". Of course I can go with a fake name like "John Smith". But that way even the people I want to know that it's me wouldn't know.

Comment: So why not enter something like 'ytg'?

Comment: The real question is why you dont want people to see your name. Placing a fake name does not help any bit with your credibility. What are you really trying to hide ? If you are just trying to hide what you post then the privacy settings have done their job.

Comment: because it was too obvious to think it could work :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only reason Twitter asks you to enter your real name is so that people you know can recognize you. But, you could also tell the people you want to follow you what your username is so they can find you.

Screenshot of name field in profile settings:

[image]

On a side note: if your account is set to be private, your friends/future followers will have to request permission to see your tweets anyway. :-P